# Number of elements to reach a cumulative sum

Tags: r, vectorization

I need to output (for a further zoo:roll_apply) the number of elements to sum to reach a certain value. Below an example:

```
  # value to reach
  vTR = c(10,15,12,13,10,15,10)
  # element to sum
  element = c(9,6,5,2,1,9,1)
  magicFoo(vTR, element) 
  # should return c(NA, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 2) 
  # 10 ~ NA, 15 <= 9+6, 12 <= 5+6+9, 13 <= 2+5+6, 10 <= 1+2+5+6...
```

For instance, I am looking for some kind of ave where k is calculated dynamically.

I could do it with a for loop but i am looking here for a more elegant way of doing this:

```
vTR = c(10,15,12,13,10,15,10)
# element to sum
element = c(9,6,5,2,1,9,1)
res = c()
j = 1
k = 0
sumE = 0
for (i in 1:length(vTR)){
  k = k+1
  sumE = sum(element[j:k])
  if (sumE < vTR[i]) {
    res[length(res)+1] = NA
    next
  }
  repeat {
    j = j + 1
    sumE = sum(element[j:k])
    if (sumE < vTR[i]) {
      j = j-1
      res[length(res)+1] = k-j +1 
      break
    }
  }
}

# > res
# [1] NA  2  3  3  4  4  2
```

Comment: What does your `sapply()` solution look like?

Comment: Thx for teaching me this, I will google how to do it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With `sapply` we can loop over each element in `vTR` and take the first `x` values , reverse them and take the cumulative sum over them and find the index when the value crosses the `vTR[x]` value.

```
sapply(seq_along(vTR),function(x) which.max(cumsum(rev(head(element, x)))>=vTR[x]))

#[1] 1 2 3 3 4 4 2
```

To get the exact expected output we can modify it by

```
sapply(seq_along(vTR), function(x) {
  val = cumsum(rev(head(element, x)))
  if (sum(val)  >= vTR[x])
    which.max(val >= vTR[x])
  else
    NA
})

#[1] NA  2  3  3  4  4  2
```

Answer (score 1):

For computation speed I slightly modified the very good [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49873273/6193177) of Ronak Shah, to run in something closer to n as n²:

```
nbIndexForCumSum = function(vTR, element) {
  rs = rev(c(0,cumsum(rev(element))))
  j = 1
  unlist(sapply(seq_along(vTR), function(x) {
    while(j > 1 & rs[j] < vTR[x] + rs[x+1]) j <<- j-1
    res = length(rs[j:x]) - which.max(rs[j:x] < vTR[x] + rs[x+1]) + 2
    j <<- ifelse(x > res, x - res, 1)
    ifelse( rs[j] < vTR[x] + rs[x+1], NA, res) 
  }) )
}
```